# content script access to webpage js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I create a firefox addon with the online addon builder. How can one use an existing function on a webpage, from within the addon? This site doesn't belong to me, so I can't bind event listeners, in order to send an event to it from my addon.

Update: Now I have this code but it doesn't work:

main.js

```
var widgets = require("widget");
var tabs = require("tabs");
var data = require("self").data;


var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "transfer",
  label: "Transfer",
  content: "Transfer",
  width: 100,
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.activeTab.attach({
      // native implementation of window.confirm will be used
      contentScriptFile: data.url("new.js")
    });
  }
});
```

new.js:

```
function foo()
{
    call(); // function in webpage

}
unsafeWindow.foo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inject a content script into the page (e.g. via `page-mod` package) and call `unsafeWindow.foo()` in the content script to call function `foo()` from the content script. See [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/access.html) for more information. Please make sure to read the warnings: you are relying on the web page function to behave the way you expect but it might not. In particular, if the function returns something and you want to process that result, you might inadvertently introduce a security hole.

Comment: @tasaras: Heh, you should write `unsafeWindow.call()`...

Comment: I did that but it says: in TypeError unsafeWindow.call is not a function, the function on the page is function call(){alert("asd");} it works fine with unsafeWindow.alert("asd")

Comment: @tasaras: Sure, a bug in your code. To call a function `call()` this function has to be actually defined in the web page...

Comment: thanks, my function was inside jquery's ready() and it couldn't find it