# Firefox extension: access window elements

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

How can a firefox extension read DOM/window objects?
I.e. reverse of: [content script access to webpage js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844633/content-script-access-to-webpage-js)

I wanted to assign a variable in the extension - using the unsafeWindow object. But it does not work. The unsafeWindow is undefined outside of contentScript:

I tried numerous other approaches but I would like to avoid the need of any ugly hacks..

For example https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/access.html says unsafeWindow is a good proxy: it sees the actual window object (even when it' modified by libraries such as jQuery). But when I try to access unsafeWindow, for example like that:
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

```
var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Mozilla website",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  onClick: function() {
tabs.activeTab.attach({
      // native implementation of window.confirm will be used
      contentScript: "console.log(window.navigator.userAgent);"
    });
dump(unsafeWindow.navigator.userAgent);

  }
dump(unsafeWindow);
});
```

Console.log works and fires an "info:" in the sdk console. but dump does not and actually there is a reference error there. I really need to access the window object from the extension. 
So is there an unsafeWindow or not?
How can I access the window object?
I will not call any functions so it is safe.

Comment: Widget might not be a good idea since it's impossible to modify the scripts on the site and contnetScripts have only a limited functionality. I must add my script file as the first one in a row.

Comment: I'll be more precise here: if the site will define window.blah=true, I can't read that from the extension. But I must...